# How to instantiate a view inside a Frame layout?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-framelayout

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    PieMenu pieMenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pieMenu = new PieMenu(getApplicationContext());

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                pieMenu.addPieMenu(x,y);
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
    return false;
    }

}
```

PieMenu:

```
public class PieMenu extends FrameLayout{

    private Context _context;
    public PieMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void addPieMenu(int x, int y){
        Toast.makeText(_context, "text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        PieItem pieView = new PieItem(_context,x,y,2);
        //FrameLayout.LayoutParams lyp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //pieView.setLayoutParams(lyp); 
        addView(pieView);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

PieItem.java:

```
public class PieItem extends View{


        private final float x;
        private final float y;
        private final int r;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


        public PieItem(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
            super(context);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        }


}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Everytime I touch the scree, the toast is being called but the circle isn't being instantiated. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way to fix this, add view in onCreate:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pieMenu = new PieMenu(getApplicationContext());

    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    fl.addView(pieMenu);

}
```

and add id to your main activity xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding `pieMenu` to any of the views in your layout (`R.layout.activity_main`)

What does your `activity_main.xml` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add created PieMenu to activity layout. You need to call something like this in onCreate method:

```
view.addView(pieMenu);
```

Or add your PieMenu to you activity_main layout.

Comment: When I do that, I get a 07-20 01:57:10.902: E/AndroidRuntime(16368): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.example.piemenu.PieMenu

Comment: he is calling addView in onTouchEvent() when an onDownAction event is captured. the problem is onDraw() is not being called.

Comment: But he didn't add pieMenu.